# CocoaPods how to install only one new library

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a list of libraries in my Pod file. I decide to add new one to Pod file. But I want to keep all my previous libraies without updates and just install (add) this one library

```
pod 'JSAnimatedImagesView', '~> 1.0.0'
```

so `pod update` and `pod install` update all libraries to newer versions, but I don't want to update them just install `pod 'JSAnimatedImagesView', '~> 1.0.0'`

Answer (score 142):

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

This installs new items without updating existing repos (versioned or not).

It's also just quicker if you have a lot of repos and want a fast install of a new item.

Comment: Although the other answers provide good practice (locking pods at particular versions) this is the correct answer to the original question.  Thanks!

Comment: WORKS Like a charm : ) Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't work for me, it still update other pods.

Answer (score 23):

*(As of March 15, 2019)*

To install 1 new pod: add the 1 desired new pod into your Podfile. Then run:

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

It will **not update any other pods** when running this.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to update the specific libraries you should lock them at the versions you want to keep

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.2.0'
pod 'JSAnimatedImagesView', '~> 1.0.0'
```

Would keep `AFNetworking` on V1.2.0 but get the latest `JSAnimatedImagesView`

This makes the podfile transferrable to other locations (and developers) and saves you from forgetting to revert your podfile until you intend to update pods

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use update command https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#pod_update

`pod update [POD_NAMES ...]`

Updates the Pods identified by the specified POD_NAMES. If no POD_NAMES are specified it updates all the Pods ignoring the contents of the Podfile.lock.

Comment: You cannot update a library that hasn't been installed

Answer (score 1):

When starting out with a project it is likely that you will want to use the latest version of a Pod. If this is the case, simply omit the version requirements.

```
pod 'SSZipArchive'
```

Later on in the project you may want to freeze to a specific version of a Pod, in which case you can specify that version number.

```
pod 'Objection', '0.9'
```

More info http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod